# How to add user in IIS Manager for FTP Site using PowerShell commands in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, iis, ftp

I want to add users for my FTP site using C# web api so, I have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504837/how-to-allow-iis-manager-user-to-a-iis-site-using-servermanager-programatically) but when I am using these commands using Powershell then, these commands successfully creating a new user. Irrespective to this when I want to automate this using below code

```
string scriptText = @"[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.Web.Management')" + "\n" +
                    "[Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.ManagementAuthentication]::CreateUser('" + UserName + "','" + Password + "')" + "\n" +
                     "[Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.ManagementAuthorization]::Grant('" + UserName + "','" + FtpSiteName + "', $FALSE)";

                Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

                runspace.Open();

                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

                pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

                Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
                runspace.Close();

                string strCmdText = "C:/Windows/System32/inetsrv/appcmd.exe set config " +
                    FtpSiteName + " - section:system.ftpServer / security / authorization / +'[accessType='Allow',users='" + UserName + "',permissions='Read, Write']' / commit:apphost";
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

then, I am receiving an error at `Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();` which is

```
{Exception calling "CreateUser" with "2" argument(s): "Filename: \\?\C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\administration.config
Error: The configuration section 'system.webServer/management/authentication' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

"}  System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord
```

According to my observation, my C# code is editing this file (C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\administration.config) where it could not find a relavent section whereas IIS Manager requires changes in this file (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\administration.config) for creating new user.

*If anything is unclear then, please let me know. Thanks.*

Comment: The parameter list (on the command line appcmd.exe set config "MyFtpSite" -section:system.ftpServer/security/authorization /+"[accessType='Allow',users='MyUser',permissions='Read, Write']" /commit:apphost)  has to be added to Process using StartInfo.  The link is adding " "www.northwindtraders.com".  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=net-5.0

Comment: Dear Jdweng, thanks for your response but my code is breaking at 
**Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();**
also, I have tried the below code separately

string strCmdText = "C:/Windows/System32/inetsrv/appcmd.exe set config " +
                    FtpSiteName + " - section:system.ftpServer / security / authorization / +'[accessType='Allow',users='" + UserName + "',permissions='Read, Write']' / commit:apphost";
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
which is not giving an error and working smoothly.

Comment: First the command appcmd.exe does not go in the startinfo.  It is the command name in the Process.Start() first parameter.  Second you have a lot of extra spaces in the pathname.  Make sure your variable strCmdText  exactly matches the working applications.

Comment: Dear Jdweng, I apologize if I couldn't elaborate you actually, I have problem at this line of code
 Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke(); i.e. relavent to powershell but not in the second part which is related to CMD. Thanks for your response.

Comment: There are three steps 1) Send Command 2) Receive Response 3) Parse Response.  You are getting an error at step 3.  You will fail step 3 if step 1 or 2 is bad.  You first have to make sure step one is correct.  Right now step one is bad.

Comment: Dear Jdweng, thanks for your prompt response but unfortunately there is no luck at my side even after trying this 
string scriptText = "[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.Web.Management');[Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.ManagementAuthentication]::CreateUser('" + UserName + "','" + Password + "')";
I am running same command on Powershell then, its working fine there.



_FYI Username and Password are two strings._

Comment: There is no need for reflection in c#!!!  I would start by running the Process and putting output into a file by redirecting the output using ">filename".   Then checking to see if the text in file is correct : appcmd.exe set config "MyFtpSite" -section:system.ftpServer/security/authorization /+"[accessType='Allow',users='MyUser',permissions='Read, Write']" /commit:apphost >c:\temp\text.txt

Comment: you could try to create the PowerShell script and run that file from your web API. 
//shell.Commands.AddScript(Input.Text);
shell.Commands.AddScript("C:\\Scripts\\PowerShell\\PowerShellScript.ps1");
Contents of this test PowerShellScript.ps1 (same as what was used in the Input control):